# XPath get attribute value xml

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes

I am using XPath in unix to get the value of attribute as follows:

```
xpath PM.xml '/*[contains(local-name(),'PM')]/*[contains(local-name(),'family')]/@eventNumber'
```

which is returning me:

```
Found 4 nodes:
-- NODE --
 eventNumber="000000"-- NODE --
 eventNumber="010000"-- NODE --
 eventNumber="020000"-- NODE --
 eventNumber="030000"
```

But here I need the value as:

```
000000
010000
020000
030000
```

After looking into some examples, I tried functions like `string()`, `text()` as follows, but didn't work.

```
SS-03:~/pankaj # xpath PM.xml '/*[contains(local-name(),'PM')]/*[contains(local-name(),'family')]/@eventNumber/text()'
No nodes found
SS-03:~/pankaj # xpath PM.xml '/*[contains(local-name(),'PM')]/*[contains(local-name(),'family')]/@eventNumber/string()'
Parse of expression /*[contains(local-name(),PM)]/*[contains(local-name(),family)]/@eventNumber/string() failed - junk after end of expression: ( at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/XML/XPath/Parser.pm line 127.
```

Please correct me where I am wrong. Also, please help me to get this using xpath only, as I have to use this in XSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is fine, that's only the way the application you used display xpath result. For example, the same xpath when used in XSL like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- set output method to be plain text -->
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <!-- using exactly the same xpath -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/*[contains(local-name(),'PM')]/*[contains(local-name(),'family')]/@eventNumber"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <!-- print attribute value -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <!-- print newline character -->
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

given the following input XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PM xmlns="foo">
  <family eventNumber="000000"/>
  <family eventNumber="010000"/>
  <family eventNumber="020000"/>
  <family eventNumber="030000"/>
</PM>
```

yield the expected values in output :

```
000000
010000
020000
030000
```

Answer (score 1):

With xpath 2.0 you can get the value of attribute with function string() at the end of your expression

```
...   /@eventNumber/string()
```

but never in xpath 1. Only by post processing or, if you waiting one result,

```
string( ...   /@eventNumber )
```

Comment: Is the syntax correct 
`SS-03:~/pankaj # xpath PM.xml 'string(/*[contains(local-name(),'PM')]/*[contains(local-name(),'family')]/@eventNumber)'` 
Output is: `Query didn't return a nodeset. Value: 000000'`

I tried some combinations also, keeping double quotes, single quotes, but didn't got  the output

Comment: Maybe it is problem of the realization. In any online xpath testre, for example, http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.htm input `<root><node eventNumber="25">text1</node></root>` and `string(//node/@eventNumber)`

Comment: @har07 i wrote - *if you waiting one result* :)